# Extract only a specific number from html table sell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this current lcode in my script which populates a cell in my sheet;

`sheet.getRange(targetcell).setFormula('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.futwiz.com/en/consumables/positions","table",1),"select Col2"),G1)');`

The output into my google sheet cell is;

"*2,800*

3 min ago"

What I would like to do is remove everything not needed, and leave ONLY the integer value 2800 (without a comma)

i.e instead of being

"*2,800*

3 min ago"

it should be

2800

Does anyone know the most elegant solution to edit my line of code to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
.setFormula(`=regexextract(INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.futwiz.com/en/consumables/positions","table",1),"select Col2"),G1),"[0-9,.]+")`)
```

Comment: That seems closer. However, the value right now should have extracted 3000 but it has only output it as 3

Comment: What is the value of G1. In my side, I have no dot, no comma. But I have updated my proposal. Let me know if it works.

Comment: value is 16, ill give it a try

Comment: perfect that worked a treat

Answer (score 1):

Solve it all in the formula itself. So place this is the .setFormula()

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 VALUE(
  SUBSTITUTE(
   REGEXEXTRACT(
    QUERY(
     IMPORTHTML("https://www.futwiz.com/en/consumables/positions","table",1),
    "select Col2 where Col2 contains '*'"),
   "\*(.*?)\*"),
  ",","")
))
```

So like this:

```
sheet.getRange(targetcell).setFormula(`=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(
   IMPORTHTML("https://www.futwiz.com/en/consumables/positions","table",1),"select Col2 where Col2 contains '*'"),"\*(.*?)\*"),",","")))`)
```

Comment: Thank you.   Im not a dev, so sorry that struggling to implement what you have suggested.

Do you mean I would replace the =INDEX part of my code with your code?

Comment: Take a look at REGEXTRACT.  You could simple wrap everything you already have in that.

Comment: @hamd01 see update

Comment: I've changed it to 

=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.futwiz.com/en/consumables/positions","table",1),"select Col2 where Col2 contains '*'"),"\*(.*?)\*"),",","")))


But the output into the cell is now just #NAME?

Comment: @hamd01 works like a charm for me. Looks like you have some weird qoutes. Just copy mine...

Comment: Like I say Im not a dev....but just looking at your script compared to my original.  My code takes the value of cell G1...for example that value might be 16, then extracts data from column 2 row 16.  Your code doesnt seem to reference the row number (whcih has to come from cell g1 for reasons I wont bore you with)